# Method successful but returns error

Tags: c#, asp.net

i used try catch in my method and i got this message "**Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.**", but the method execution is successful (data are saved in the database).
Here is my code:

```
            try
            {
                //saving EmailMoney Table and Transactions Table
                string EmailMoneyCode = HelperClasses.Globals.RandomString(20);
                LogicLayer.Entities.Transaction NewTransaction = new LogicLayer.Entities.Transaction();

                NewTransaction.EmailMoneyTransaction.EmailRecipientID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRecipients.SelectedValue);
                NewTransaction.EmailMoneyTransaction.EmailMoneyGeneratedCode = EmailMoneyCode;

                NewTransaction.SourceAccountID = VirtualAccountIDFrom;
                NewTransaction.SourceCurrencyID = CurrencyIDFrom;
                NewTransaction.SourceAmount = AmountToWithdraw;
                NewTransaction.ReceivingAmount = Amount;
                NewTransaction.Fee = FeeConverted;
                NewTransaction.SubTransactionType = DataLayer.Enums.RefSubTransactionType.EmailTransfer;

                NewTransaction.Save();
                UpdateVABalance(VirtualAccountIDFrom, AmountToWithdraw);
                Response.Redirect("EmailMoney.aspx?notif=1");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                divNotif.Attributes["class"] = "notibar msgerror";
                divNotif.InnerHtml = "<a class=\"close\"></a><p>" + ex.Message + "</p>";
                return;
            }
```

How can I resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should remove the `try catch` and see exactly where the exception was thrown at.

Comment: where exactly(at which line) you are getting error??

Comment: @KingKing  I removed the try catch, there is no error and the method is successfully executed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.Redirect(url)` will give you this error, [Redirect as below with the second argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Response.Redirect("EmailMoney.aspx?notif=1",false);
```